# Commercial Dedicated vs Shared Residential Internet

Tags: bandwidth, connection, colocation

I recently purchased a server to mess around with. I want to be able to host a few of my own sites, but my home internet is about 5Mbps up and down. I was looking into colo at my local DC and they are asking $50/mo for 1Mbps up/down. They are saying they are giving me a commercial dedicated connection, dual providers, and so on.

My first question is that a fair price for a 1Mbps connection? Both my home internet and their internet have unlimited data transfer (or at least limits I would never go over), so I am wondering if there is anything wrong with using my home connection? Would it be fast enough to handle about 10 websites with 100 visiters a day each? Why would their seemingly slower connection be any better?

Answer (score -1):

Is it a fair price? Seems to be, yes.

Residential-grade is just that - good enough for Facebook, Netflix, and Youtube. Nothing about your residential connection is guaranteed, and it's likely against your TOS to use it for providing services.

The bandwidth you're purchasing from a Colo is provided via redundant network systems, redundant internet connections from varied providers, backed by redundant power systems, and is guaranteed bandwidth.

As for how much bandwidth your users will use, well that's up to you to determine. Theres no "bandwidth per day per user" magic metric I can throw at you.

To conclude, **do not** use your home internet connection for this.

Comment: I am just going to host a few personal sites and my isp is fairly consistent with their network speed. In an ideal world where my isp always provided me with 5Mbps and never went down,same with my power, would there be any other disadvantages to hosting my sites from home?

Comment: Answering off topic questions implicitly encourages them.

Comment: @iain It was not clear that this was off-topic until his comment.